# Let $R=\mathbb Z_{36}$. Find $N(\langle 0 \rangle), N(\langle 4\rangle), N(\langle 6 \rangle)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, nilpotence

Let $R=\mathbb Z_{36}$. Find $N(\langle 0 \rangle), N(\langle 4\rangle), N(\langle 6 \rangle)$.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $A$ be any ideal of $R$. Then the *nilradical of A*, $N(A)=\{r\in R: r^n \in A \text{ for some positive integer } n\}$ is an ideal of $R$.

I understand the definition, but I'm not entirely sure how to compute in general the nilradicals of these principal ideals.

I recognize that $N(\langle 0 \rangle)$ is really the same as the nilpotent elements in $R$, which in this case would be the nilpotent elements in $\mathbb Z_{36}$. I found [here](https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-7-1-13.html#:%7E:text=An%20element%20x%20%E2%88%88%20R,prime%20divisor%20of%20also%20divides%20.) that in $\mathbb Z_n$ an element $a$ is nilpotent iff every prime divisor of $n$ also divides $a$. Therefore, since $36=2^23^2$ the nilpotent elements in $\mathbb Z_{36}$ are $6$ and $12$. (**Edit:** I just realized that these would *not* be the only nilradical elements, by the theorem I just stated. Whoops! It would also include $18,24,30,36=0$)

Extending this logic to the other ones, we see that $4=2^2$ and $6=2\cdot 3$, so elements of $N(\langle 4 \rangle)$ must be divisible by $2$ and elements of $N(\langle 6 \rangle)$ must be divisible by $2$ and $3$.

Therefore, $N(\langle 4 \rangle) = \mathbb Z_{36} \cap 2\mathbb Z$, and $N(\langle 6 \rangle) = \mathbb Z_{36}\cap 6\mathbb Z$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, up to a minor problem of notation: $\mathbb Z_{36}\cap k\mathbb Z$ makes no sense ($\mathbb Z_{36}$ is a set of $\bmod{36}$-classes, whereas $k\mathbb Z$ is a set of integers). The correct notation is $k\mathbb Z_{36}$, or simply $\langle k\rangle$. So yes: $N(\langle4\rangle)=\langle2\rangle$ and $N(\langle0\rangle)=N(\langle6\rangle)=\langle6\rangle$.

More generaly, in $\mathbb Z_n$, $N(\langle m\rangle)=\langle$[rad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)$(\gcd(m,n))\rangle$: see [How can I calculate the radical of an ideal in ring ${\Bbb Z}_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231824/how-can-i-calculate-the-radical-of-an-ideal-in-ring-bbb-z-n)